# What's the group extension corresponding to the sum of 2 classes of $H^2(G,A)$

Tags: group-theory, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology, group-extensions, galois-cohomology

I'm learning Galois/Group Cohomology and i've just seen that the second cohomology group $H^2(G,A)$ (constructed as the factor systems quotient splitting factors) classifies the group extensions of $G$ with abelian kernel $A$ up to equivalence.

My question is, given 2 extensions $$1\to A\to E\to G\to 1$$ and $$1\to A\to E'\to G\to 1$$ with cohomology classes $[c]$ and $[c']$ respectively ($[c]\ne [c']$), what is the extension (or the class of equivalent extensions) with cohomology class $[c]+[c']$ (assuming it is non-trivial)? Does it have a general form or it depends on the specific case?

I have not found it anywhere so I would appreciate some book where I can find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension corresponding to the sum of cohomology classes represented by the two original extensions is called the *Baer sum* of the two extensions.

It can be defined using just group theory without cohomology.

Comment: Thank you, do you know any book where I could read about it?